# Python Scripts no longer run

Tags: python, selenium

I have a problem when running some python scripts. I get the message 'Ran 0 tests in 0.000s'.

This occured out of know where. Soem scripts still do work however. I can't find any difference between the scripts as why some should run and some don't.

I've done a bit of research and 'unittest' seems to be a common theme. As far as I know I dind't change my code and I've included import unittest.

I don't feel there is a need to post my code as there's no difference (except for the name odf the file) between the scripts that run and the scripts that don't run.

Any ideas?

Comment: How are you running them from the command line? The name of the script should have no effect whatsoever on what part of it the python interpreter runs. If they're literally the same script renamed, something has gone horribly wrong with your Python installation.

Comment: Like this....... python template_test1.py

Comment: How did you write the main part? I mean how did you call your tests?

Answer (score 0):

You are running them as unittests instead of normally. Are you using Eclipse? You're probably pressing the wrong button.

Comment: No, I'm running them from the command line. The thing I can think that I may have done was move my files into a differnt folder. But even when I move them back to their original place they still don't run

Comment: What are you giving to the commandline? Are you doing unittests with the ones that are working / what do you get when they do work?

Comment: for example: python template_test1.py   Here is how I name my file..... class template_test1(unittest.TestCase):                  I run all the tests the same. If they work I get ........        Ran 1 tests in 14.000s'